# Why is deleting the .m2-directory causing maven compilation errors?

Tags: java, maven

As I was having troubles building a project with docker, I tried debugging the problem without containers. I was able to reproduce it by deleting the `~/.m2` directory. After I run `mvn clean compile`, plugins and dependencies are present in the .m2 folder - including the dependency referenced in the error message - but the error persists. As soon as I restore the old `.m2` folder from a backup, I am able to complete the compilation again. As I have many dependencies in the original `.m2` folder, I have a hard time checking for relevant differences between a fresh `.m2` folder and the old one. Does anyone have an idea what state the folder holds that could cause the issue?

I was also googling the error itself, but nothing seems to help. Appreciate every help here as well of course.

This is the error message I get (same output for docker as well as the 'local' build):

```
$ mvn clean compile
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ---------------------< org.example:jnanomsg_tests >---------------------
[INFO] Building jnanomsg_tests 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ jnanomsg_tests ---
[INFO] Deleting /home/youri/dev/uni/fp/jnanomsg_tests_2/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ jnanomsg_tests ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ jnanomsg_tests ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 3 source files to /home/youri/dev/uni/fp/jnanomsg_tests_2/target/classes
[...]
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.343 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-08-09T19:07:30+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project jnanomsg_tests: Compilation failure: Compilation failure: 
[ERROR] /home/youri/dev/uni/fp/jnanomsg_tests_2/src/main/java/Broker.java:[13,45] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   variable Domain
[ERROR]   location: class nanomsg.Nanomsg
[ERROR] /home/youri/dev/uni/fp/jnanomsg_tests_2/src/main/java/Broker.java:[16,45] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   variable Domain
[ERROR]   location: class nanomsg.Nanomsg
[ERROR] /home/youri/dev/uni/fp/jnanomsg_tests_2/src/main/java/Broker.java:[19,56] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   method getFd()
[ERROR]   location: variable s1 of type nanomsg.pubsub.SubSocket
[ERROR] /home/youri/dev/uni/fp/jnanomsg_tests_2/src/main/java/Broker.java:[19,68] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   method getFd()
[ERROR]   location: variable s2 of type nanomsg.pubsub.PubSocket
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

This is the `pom.xml` for what it's worth:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>clojars-repo</id>
            <name>Clojars custom repo</name>
            <url>https://clojars.org/repo/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>jnanomsg_tests</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jnanomsg</groupId>
            <artifactId>jnanomsg</artifactId>
            <version>0.4.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Comment: Well you seem to have en error in the `Broker.class` Can you please check what the compiler is complaining about in this class.